# Trial ball in international matches

Tags: rules, cricket

Is there any chance of bowling a trial ball before the start of the innings in international cricket history like street cricket or local cricket matches?

Answer if yes:

- When did they stop this practice?
- What is the reason for that?

If No:

- What is the reason for not including this sportive thing in
  international cricket?

Comment: I don't think any justification needs to be given for it _not_ being included. If one thinks that international cricket should include a trial ball, then one needs to make a case for it. I can't see how sportsmanship has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial ball is not permitted in international cricket. There is [no law](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-17-practice-on-the-field/) regarding this. If any trial ball would be allowed, [there would be a law on that](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/penalty-runs-for-hitting-on-to-the-helmet-of-the-wicket-keeper-which-he-is-weari/2695#comment5458_2695).

Also, there is a law regarding trial *run up*. ([17.4](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-17-practice-on-the-field/))

> #### 4.Trial run up
>
> A bowler is permitted to have a trial run up provided the umpire is
> satisfied that it will not contravene either of Laws 42.9 (Time
> wasting by the fielding side) or 42.13 (Fielder damaging the pitch).

So it is clear that a bowler can take a trial run up but can't bowl a trial ball (after taking a run up). Mostly opening bowlers take trial run up (maybe to adjust on the field).

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot practice on the pitch see [The Laws of Cricket](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-17-practice-on-the-field,43,AR.html). The reason is the state of the pitch, and any wear on it, is an important part of how a game of cricket unfolds. Practicing on the pitch would alter its state and therefore could be used as a tactic in some way, so is not permitted.

Comment: good answer, but qn is not about practice, it's about trial ball which is bowled in our street cricket matches

Comment: Whether you call it practice and warm up or a 'trial ball' the rules are very clear that it is not permitted on the pitch for the reasons given. International cricketers certainly warm up before the game, generally on the outfield, you're just not allowed to do so on the match pitch itself.

Comment: Sorry, first sentence should read "Whether you call it practice OR warm up..". Too old to edit.

Comment: ur answer is, `in international cricket history trial balls were not bowled in any match` is it?

Comment: in ur answer, `Practicing on the pitch would alter its state and therefore could be used as a tactic in some way, so is not permitted.` Iam not asking about practicing in the pitch,it's abt `just bowl a single ball to the opening batsman by the opening bowler which is not counted in the match.` did u get me?

Comment: Have you read the link I posted?